# Fetch value from one of two HTML elements with same ID

Tags: javascript, html, prototypejs

I have two span's which contain a HTML text box with same id say "field1". Based on a drop down value, only of these two span's are shown in the screen at a given time. Either one of the span's is shown or none of them are shown.

I am using `.hide();` and `.show();` in prototype js to show and hide these span's based on the drop down value. But whenever I try to get the value by `$F('field1');` on submit, I only get the first HTML text box's value(which is empty).

Is there a way I can solve this to get the value of visible HTML text box value?

Comment: No two elements should ever have the same ID - it must be a unique identifier. Doing so violates the DTD. Change the elements to have differen IDs.

Comment: Use class instead of ID for 2 elements.

Comment: @Polynomial Yes I agree with that, but due to some reasons I am forced to use the same ID for both the components. Like, I am using Spring. The HTML element's form ID should be mapped to one single form object as only one of them is going to be available at a time. So I could not have different IDs. In Spring the <form:path.. transforms itself as HTML ID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use class. ID for an element should be unique as it's an ID ;)

1. select all elements with specified class name. you will get an array of elements having specified class name.

   ```
   var eleCollection = document.getElementByClassName("anyClassName");
   ```
2. After this, u can loop through this array of elements and get their values

   ```
   for(element in eleCollection) {
       var thisValue = element.getAttribute("value");
      console.log("Element: ",element," value: ",value);
   }
   ```

Comment: So when I loop through I get each element, how do I get the value of the text box? should I be using <element-name>.innerHTML?

Comment: If you're using Prototype, I'd suggest sticking with the Prototype ways of doing things. `$$()` instead of `document.getElementByClassName()`, `array.each()` instead of `for (var in array)`, etc

Answer (score 4):

`id` should be unique within a page.

I am assuming you have different dropdown values. If so, assign different `id`'s to these spans and use selected dropdown value to pick one of them.